# adal.js acquireToken not executing callback

Tags: typescript, office365, adal.js

I'm trying to build a single page app using Typescript and jquery (no angular) that calls the SharePoint API's. Unfortunately, the call to acquireToken is simply not triggering its callback. The basic structure is as follows...

```
import AuthenticationContext = require('adal-angular');

const config = {
  instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
  tenant: "[tenant id]",
  clientId: "[app id from AAD]",
  postLogoutRedirectUri: windows.location.origin,
  cacheLocation: "localStorage"
}
export class BasicApp {
  public constructor() {}
  public init() : void {
    const authCtx = new AuthorizationContext(config);
    authCtx.handleWindowCallback(window.location.hash);

    this.user = authCtx.getCachedUser();
    $('#actionButton').click(() => this.someAction());
  }

  public someAction(): void {
    const authCtx = new AuthorizationContext(config);
    const resourceId: string = "https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com";
    if(this.user){
      console.log("Getting token...");
      authCtx.acquireToken(resourceId, function(error, callback){
        //none of this gets executed
        if(error || !token){
          console.log("Some error occurred");
          return;
        }
        console.log("Got the token");
      });
    }      
  }
}

const myApp = new BasicApp();
myApp.init();
```

There's a bit more to it (obviously) but this is the critical code - from what I can tell.

I can see the adal.js code iframe created when I debug in Chrome but my callback function never gets called.

Interestingly, in the same app src, I tried this code (https://www.itunity.com/article/calling-office-365-apis-jquery-adaljs-2758) and it works fine so I don't think it's my AAD configuration or anything like that.

Any pointers or guidance here? I have been banging my head against the wall on this one for days.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: No. It seems like it has something to do with the frame timing out or receiving an error but I've had to divert my attention elsewhere so I never tracked it down. Let me know if you figure out. Sorry!